# Prolog Merge two element of a List

Tags: list, prolog

i have to merge two equal elements of a list like this:

```
[1,2,3,4,5,5,6,7,5,6] => [1,2,3,4,55,6,7,5,6]
```

How can i do this in prolog? Thanks All.

Comment: What do you expect for `[1,5,5,5,7]`? Do you expect ascending values?

Comment: Note: I want to select the number... example i want merge 5 then [1,2,2,3,4,5,5,6] -> [1,2,2,3,4,55,6]

Answer (score 1):

Something like that ?

```
my_merge(N, L, R) :-
    merge(N, L, [], R).

merge(_, [], R, R1) :-
    reverse(R, R1).


merge(N, [M | T], CR, FR) :-
    N \= M,
    merge(N, T, [M |CR], FR).


merge(N, [N | T], CR, FR) :-
    merge_(N, T, N, CR, FR).


merge_(N, [M| T], X, CR, FR) :-
    M \= N,
    merge(N, [M | T], [X | CR], FR).


merge_(N, [N| T], X, CR, FR) :-
    X1 is X * 10 + N,
    merge_(N, T, X1, CR, FR).


merge_(_N, [], X, CR, FR) :-
    reverse([X | CR], FR).
```

Comment: `my_merge(5,[5,5,5],R).` fails.

Comment: +1, better remove the EDIT thing, if anyone wants to get the precise history, they can look at it anyway.

Answer (score 1):

abusing of Prolog flexible data representation, we can do this way:

```
fuse_consec([E,E|L], E, [N|F]) :-
    !, fuse_consec([E|L], E, [R|F]),
    atom_concat(E, R, C),
    atom_number(C, N).
fuse_consec([X|L], E, [X|F]) :-
    fuse_consec(L, E, F).
fuse_consec([], _, []).
```

test

```
?- fuse_consec([1,2,3,4,5,5,6,7,5,6],5,L).
L = [1, 2, 3, 4, 55, 6, 7, 5, 6].
```

Comment: `atom_concat/3` should produce an error for the first argument being an integer.  Only SWI handles this differently. Your version is not tail recursive but still uses a cut.

Comment: @false: the cut seems necessary to avoid the subsequent copy rule, I prefer it here instead of a if/then/else, being less verbose. What's the ISO portable alternative to atom_concat? I initially avoided also atom_number, getting atoms (it's not clearly stated in the question if elements are numbers, just in a comment)

Comment: Maybe you missed my first comment: This program is not ISO and SWI/YAP specific.